# Spices and Foods to Trade

Tags: magic, economy, food

Assuming a medieval setting, what kind of spices, foods, seasonings etc. . . are available to trade. Handwave transporting them and assume any and every possible biome to choose from.

EDIT: Okay so assuming magic is used for transport or preservation. And transport is mainly by boat or caravan. And I am looking for spices and exotic foods like coffee that aren't found in europe. Think Asia and Africa.

Comment: And how does magic play a part into it?

Comment: There are an awful lot of spices and food out there. I'd suggest you consider limiting yourself to just spices, and perhaps gear the question toward one facet of spice trade in particular. Also, it doesn't hurt to at least *try* a google first. :)

Comment: If you handwave the transport and can choose from every possible biome, then every spice and food in the world is available to trade.

Comment: "Handwave transporting them" - that's a very big handwave. In ancient/medieval times, agriculture products had commercial potential precisely if they were transportable. In modern times, almost anything is traded because produce can be easily stored and transported.

Comment: Depends on the cultures you're trading to. People will pay for some strange things if their culture deems it fashionable.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.oldcook.com/en/medieval-spices, at the end of the 10th century the spice trade deals primarily with *pepper, cinnamon, ginger*, and also *galangal* and *clove*.

The link also lists: *cardamom, cinnamon flower, cubeb, "grains of Paradise", mastic, nard, nutmeg and mace, [black] pepper, long pepper, saffron, sugar, sumac, spikenard* introduced over the next few centuries.

(Interesting to learn that many of these were medicines before they were spices…)

Answer (score 0):

If you handwave away transportation and preservation, than ... any food or spice that exists anywhere in the world. What would prevent someone from trading a food item OTHER THAN it is too expensive to transport or it will go bad before it could get to the destination? Well, maybe you could add cultural issues about what people see as desirable to eat.